# How to override Slack channels in Travis-CI notification when encrypting the token?

Tags: travis-ci, slack-api

The online documentation for Travis-CI notification on Slack says:

> Overriding the channel is also possible, just add it to the configuration with a # separating them from account and token.

```
notifications:
  slack: '<account>:<token>#development'
```

However, if I want to encrypt the credentials the way it is recommended:

```
travis encrypt "<account>:<token>" --add notifications.slack
```

will work just fine.  But when I try:

```
travis encrypt "<account>:<token>#development" --add notifications.slack
```

I get a new encrypted token, but the notifications come on the default channel set up at integration time.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: we use enterprise versions of everything (Slack, Travis, GitHub), in case this may play a role.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command **isn't** correct, it's missing the `.rooms` property at the end. It should be

```
travis encrypt "account:token#channel" --add notifications.slack.rooms
```

Answer (score 2):

the encrypt command is correct:

```
travis encrypt "account:token#channel" --add notifications.slack
```

but the result inside the .travis.yml will be (wrong, and that's the problem):

```
notifications:
    slack: 
       secure: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

> you have to edit the .travis.yml manually after the encrypt command **and add rooms**, so correct is:

```
notifications:
  slack:
    rooms:
      secure: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the following encryption command, for every slack channel you want to include in the notifications.  **Make sure you keep a copy of each secure encrypted message** as the command will overwrite your `travis.yml` every time it is run.

```
travis encrypt "account:token#channel1" --add notifications.slack.rooms
travis encrypt "account:token#channel2" --add notifications.slack.rooms
```

Finally add the tokens for each channel in the following format:

```
notifications:
  slack:
    rooms:
      - secure: secure_token_for_channel1
      - secure: secure_token_for_channel2
```